# apt update: signatures were invalid: F42ED6FBAB17C654

Tags: ros, ros2, buildfarm, apt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit2: for full details, see [ROS GPG Key Expiration Incident](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-gpg-key-expiration-incident/20669) on ROS Discourse. For a summary of the fix, see the accepted answer below.

---

Edit: removed the work-around. Don't use it. See the answer below.

---

On 2021-05-28, the signing key of the ROS `apt` repositories expired.

`apt update` output will be like this:

```
$ apt update
...
Err:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG F42ED6FBAB17C654 Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>
...
Reading package lists... Done                         
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG F42ED6FBAB17C654 Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This will cause CIs to fail and regular `apt update`s on user machines as well (ie: installing ROS using `apt` is currently not possible).

See [Key for downloading ros2 source showing expired](https://discourse.ros.org/t/key-for-downloading-ros2-source-showing-expired/20662) on ROS Discourse for where this is being discussed.

See [GPG Key Expired](https://status.ros.org/incidents/mhqz8yyhrtsg) for the incident report.

Work is underway to fix this -- which will likely be a replacement of the current key.

If/when more information is available, I'll update this Q&A.

Related issues:

- [ros/rosdistro#29715](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/29715): key expiration
- [osrf/docker_images#535](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/issues/535): Docker image updates

Related PRs:

- [ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config#205](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/pull/205)
- [ros2/ros_buildfarm_config#163](https://github.com/ros2/ros_buildfarm_config/pull/163)
- [ros/rosdistro#29716](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/29716)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379190/apt-update:-signatures-were-invalid:-f42ed6fbab17c654/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-29

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-29**:
Discourse thread about the previous key change: [New GPG keys deployed for packages.ros.org](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-gpg-keys-deployed-for-packages-ros-org/9454). Previous Q&A: #q325039.

Note: the information in those posts does **not** necessarily help with the current expired key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit 2: in case of Docker images/containers still complaining about expired keys: Docker's layer caching could be interfering there. As the key's signature hasn't changed (only it's expiration date), the command to import the key is identical to what it was before the key update.

This could cause Docker's caching to decide to *not* run the command, causing the expired key to still become part of the image.

Running `docker build` with `--no-cache` or introducing a change in the affected `Dockerfile` (before the key import) would invalidate the cache and should result in the new key getting imported.

Note: the official `ros` and `osrf/ros` Docker images have all been updated with the new key.

---

Edit: there are reports the ROS 2 specific mitigation doesn't work for some users.

The ROS 1 `curl` command should work in that case.

---

From [ROS GPG Key Expiration Incident](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-gpg-key-expiration-incident/20669) on ROS Discourse:

> To fix this issue users need to update the public key used for ROS apt repositories. To do this for ROS 1 installations one needs to run a single command, namely:
>
> ```
> curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> For ROS 2 installations you will need to run this command:
>
> ```
> sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
> ```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 41

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arunbalaji](https://answers.ros.org/users/81437/arunbalaji/) on 2021-08-17**:
thank you worked

**Comment by [yin-ye](https://answers.ros.org/users/82412/yin-ye/) on 2021-08-26**:
This solved my issue, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an issue relating to an expired key on the ROS build farm. We'll be posting updated instructions on [ROS discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/t/key-for-downloading-ros2-source-showing-expired/20662) shortly.

[Update can be found here.](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-gpg-key-expiration-incident/20669)

---

Originally posted by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) with karma: 209 on 2021-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2021-05-29**:
https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-gpg-key-expiration-incident/20669

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this issue referring this : https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/742#issuecomment-509685308

`$ curl http://repo.ros2.org/repos.key | sudo apt-key add -`

---

Originally posted by [kamal_nathan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45487/kamal_nathan/) with karma: 143 on 2021-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LSD](https://answers.ros.org/users/62065/lsd/) on 2021-06-03**:
This answer helped me with my ROS2 docker image.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-05**:
Note: you're downloading over HTTP. That's not a secure way to download a key file.